# Как скрыть часть содержимого,выступающего за пределы блока без использования overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как скрыть часть содержимого,выступающего за пределы родительского блока без использования свойства `overflow`? Дело в том что необходимо скрыть выборочно выступающие части `content`, а  элементы `span` оставить видимыми, они располагаются за пределами `container`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  Width: 200%;
}

span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  z-index: 100;
}

span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>left</span>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <span>right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавить ещё один контейнер

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть `css` привели.

Comment: Вот привёл,посмотрите

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В css для этого ничего особенного не предусмотрено. Но, если подумать, то общий случай с  overflow подходит и для частных случаев типа вашего. Вы хотите скрыть содержимое div.content, но не скрывать span, тогда overflow: auto следует применить именно к div.content, просто сделав его по размерам совпадающим с контейнером.

Если надо дополнительно позиционировать содержимое контейнера, оберните содержимое в блок с позиционированием. Если надо выровнять кнопки, используйте flex (или другие способы).

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: 0;
}

span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>left</span>
  <div class="content">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
  <span>right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Нельзя менять ширину content! Он должен быть шире основного контейнера. Эти выступающие за контейнер излишки должны быть, их просто необходимо скрыть, не скрывая span

Comment: @ArturHan просто добавте обёртку. `<div class="wrapper" style="width=100%; overflow: auto;"><div class="content">...</div></div>`

Comment: да,пожалуй,так должно получиться.Спасибо!